# What underlying semantic notions connect the notion of 'thrown or hitting on both sides' to 'Amphiboly'?

Tags: terminology, fallacies, greeks

<sub>Source: p 108, *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (6 ed, 2000) by [York U. Prof. S. Morris Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel)</sub>

> The *fallacy of amphiboly** is the product of poor sentence structure. It results when words are incorrectly or loosely grouped in a sentence, giving rise to a meaning not intended by the author.
>
> [I omit this book's deficient etymology of 'amphiboly'.]

OED redirects [amphiboly](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/6643#eid5042001) to [amphibole](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/6630#eid5028322); the latter's Etymology states:

> < French amphibole, 1. adj. ‘ambiguous, of a double sense’ (Cotgrave 1611), 2. the mineral;
> < Latin amphibol-um ambiguous,
> < Greek ἀμϕίβολ-ον `thrown or hitting on both sides`, ambiguous,
> < ἀμϕί on both sides + βολ-, βαλ- stem of βάλλ-ειν to throw.

What underlying semantic notions connect the notion of `thrown or hitting on both sides` (from the Ancient Greek etymon) to the modern definition in Informal Logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amphiboly or amphibology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity) stays for *Syntactic ambiguity*, i.e.

> a situation where a sentence may be interpreted in more than one way due to ambiguous sentence structure.

*Ambiguity* is also the word used in the translation of [Sophistical Refutations](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Sophistical_Elenchi):

> [165b23-166a22.] Examples such as the following depend upon *ambiguity*: ‘I wish that you the enemy may capture.’ And ‘He who knows that, that knows’; for by this phrase one may signify as the knower either him who knows or that which is known.

The ethymology for the Ancient Greek [*ἀμφίβολος*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0058:entry=a%29mfi%2Fbolos) is:

> **I**. put round, encompassing, **Eur**.
>
> **II**. attacked on both or all sides, **Aesch**.
>
> **III**. doubtful, ambiguous, **Plat., Xen.**, etc.

Thus, we have a "shift of meaning" from **II** to the figurative usage **III**: a sentence that can be undestood in two different ways not because the words *per se* are ambiguous, but due to the syntactical construction of the phrase.